# Error converting data type varchar to varbinary in sql only for few values

Tags: sql-server

```
IF(ISNUMERIC(RTRIM(LTRIM('83B1B88'))) = 0)
select CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARBINARY, CONVERT(VARCHAR, '0x' + '83B1B88'), 1)))
```

I am not sure why sql is throwing Error converting data type varchar to varbinary
I am getting this exception only for values like `1B91B32`,`169DF90`,  `13077B5`

Can anyone help me out ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're passing a style of `1` to [`CONVERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql).

> If the data_type is a binary type, the expression must be a character expression. The expression must be composed of an even number of hexadecimal digits (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, A, B, C, D, E, F, a, b, c, d, e, f). If the style is set to 1 the characters 0x must be the first two characters in the expression. **If the expression contains an odd number of characters or if any of the characters are invalid an error is raised.**

My emphasis.

All of your examples of invalid sequences appear to have odd lengths. You should add a padding `0` if you have an odd length sequence. Whether you pad at the start or the end depends on your exact requirements, where the sequence came from, etc.

Comment: The convert function is too problematic, I will advice you go with the cast function very simple to use and does not have rule of the number of character or style.                             `CAST('YOUR STRING VALUE' AS VARBINARY(LEN))`         for instance you can have                    `CAST('83B1B88' AS VARBINARY(50))` assuming your column is of length 50. @Amit @ibubi

Comment: @AbayomiApetu - I don't understand what point you're trying to make. There are no limitations on the types that can be used with `CAST` or `CONVERT`. But the latter gives you *additional* control over the conversion process via the *style* parameter.

Comment: @[Damien_The_Unbeliever](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15498/damien-the-unbeliever) I am not disputing your answer, just that I tried working with it without any success but going the `CAST` direction worked without any issue. I did not have to monitor the number of the character be passed in by the user neither do I need to manually add `0x` to the string to be converted. It worked as started above. Thank you for the insight.